# How to literally print \n in string using php

Tags: php, string, parsing, newline

I need to literally print `\n` inside of the the `this.value.split`

```
$rows .= "<textarea onkeyup='this.rows = (this.value.split(\"\n\").length||1);' ...
```

I cut the code short so its easier to read.

PHP parses it as a new line.  How can I rewrite this string so that it will actually print `\n` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to backslash your backslash:

```
\\n
```

Alternatively, you could use single quotes to delimit your string, but this would mean you would have to escape all the literal single quotes.

Here is a demonstration: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/s7g-ra9

Comment: Booo 5 seconds before me just bc I had to add a second part :-P

Comment: still printing blank.  try it!  try echoing out a textarea with that js function included

Comment: wait this is working..  i feel like something else in my code is removing the new line  odd

Comment: it works when i simplify it at least.  i will accept this answer when it becomes available

Comment: @Neal You snooze you lose :P

Answer (score 5):

Two ways:

```
echo "\\n"; //escape it

echo '\n'; //use single quotes
```